# How can I turn off a ceiling heat panel with only a setting dial?

Tags: heater

I have a heater at work that’s been put into the ceiling , almost looks like an RV heater. It’s about 40” x 40” and has one black dial for high and low. I turned this on because it was getting cold outside and I have no idea how to turn such a device off with no off switch at all. All my life I’ve never seen a heater without an off switch.

I can’t mess with the breakers because there's stuff in my office that can’t be powered off.  Is there a way to turn these heaters off? Almost forgot, it turns a full 360 over and over there’s no tighten loosen option for it.

Comment: Maybe there's a detent on the dial between low and off. A few photos might help identify the unit. Of course, if this is at work, there's someone there you can ask.

Comment: Why aren't you asking the property owner?

Comment: It was at night on a weekend, and I didn’t want to ruin anyone’s time if I didn’t have too, it finally shut off though after ten minutes of leaving it alone

Comment: Keep in mind it's not that uncommon for heaters to *do what you would call "run"* for some time after you commanded an action.  It actually is obeying your command promptly (assuming short cycling isn't an issue) -- it is simply "doing an orderly shutdown".  For instance if it's an electric heater with a blower, it may have turned off the electric heat *instantly*, but the blower runs longer to prevent damage to the heating coils.  Maybe while you were trying to turn it off, you broke the knob?  Have the super fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be a smart-as here but you said, "I turned this on". Wouldn't doing the opposite of what you did turn it off. What was different between on and off? Also, there should be some sort of a manufacturer or model number on it. You may have to remove a decorative shroud. If you know that you should be able to Google the instructions for it.